# How to verify the distance between 2 coordinates?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-markers

I'm using this method to calculate distance between 2 coordinates

```
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#findnearsql
```

for example i have two coordinates(lat and lng)

```
first coordinate: 37, -122
second coordinate:37.386337, -122.085823
```

I get this distance 27.1097282198804(miles) between these coordinates by using the method above.

Please tell me any way to verify this distance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use the Google Maps API [Geometry Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html).

```
firstLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37,-122);
secondLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.386337, -122.085823);
distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(firstLatLng,secondLatLng);
```

Comment: I used this to verify the results

    http://www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.java.html

works perfectly fine.